# whereBetween with registration_date in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have stored users registration data with their registration date. I have two select lists in my form
 1) from - for from date
 2) to - for to date
 and there is a filter button to display data as per the selected from and to values of select list.
Here is my code -

```
if($request->from_date && $request->to_date)
        {
            $from=$request->from_date;
            $to=$request->to_date;
            $users=DB::table('registration')->whereBetween('reg_date',[$from,$to])->paginate(5);
        }
```

It is not showing proper data.
I just want that when I click on filter button, data should be fetch as per the selected from and to values of select list.
How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by proper data

Comment: Can you show us an example of what `$from` and `$to` equal?  What format are they?

Comment: Date format is d-m-Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($request->from_date && $request->to_date)
{
     $from = $request->from_date; 
     $to = $request->to_date;
     $users=DB::table('registration')->where('reg_date','>',$from)->where('reg_date','<',$to)->paginate(5);
}
```

Comment: It is showing error - A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Date format stored in database - 09-06-2015  As per that I made changes in your code but still not working.

Comment: It is again showing error - A non well formed numeric value encountered . I stored date in varchar

Comment: well thats the problem, just show the output of $request->from_date

Comment: Output of $request->from_date - 09-06-2015

Comment: try the edited ans, if it doesnt work change the column to date and not varchar

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$users=DB::table('registration')->where('reg_date','>',$from)->where('reg_date','<',$to)->paginate(5);
```

I am not sure, maybe it works only where the table field is `int` or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `whereRaw` Function of Laravel where you can enter Raw Where Clause

Try the Code Below

```
if ($request->has('from_date') && $request->has('to_date')) {
    $from = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->input('from_date'))->format('Y-m-d');
    $to = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->input('to_date'))->format('Y-m-d');
    $users=DB::table('registration')->whereRaw("DATE(`reg_date`) >= '".$from."' AND DATE(`reg_date`) <= '".$to."'")->paginate(5)
}
```

Just a suggestion, instead of `$request->from_date` check you may use `$request->has('from_date')` to check whether the parameter exists or not.